# Short range communication (Bluetooth, NFC ?)

Tags: java, android, ios, bluetooth, nfc

Hello StackOverflowers,

i'm having an idea of an application that I could develop, I'm facing some technical issues though. 
Basically, my usecase : I need to broadcast an image on short range (min 10, max 100 meters), and also be able to send a quick message (nothing handwritten, more like a poke).

The whole idea is to not have to be online, at least not use a webserver to communicate. Something peer-to-peer, basically. I've seen android comes with the createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord() for bluetooth, what is it worth ? Will that be a solution to my use case if both the devices have the application running ? Does it come with breaches, like man-in-the-middle or even a direct breach if the hacker has the application on his own device ?

Are there any other viable solutions ?

Cheers

Comment: My choice would be Wifi P2P on that case. Since bluetooth or NFC will cover only few metres. But wifi has better coverage range. Also android has wifi p2p Manager for these connections. Just check about it.

Comment: NFC is definitely out, because of its (very low) range. Wifi P2P is a really nice way. Bluetooth would also work. Nothing else viable that I know off.

Comment: Thank you both for your inputs. Does Wifi P2P need any extra consideration that I should be aware of ? Specifically, i'd need to broadcast an image to whoever might be in range, which means there can't be any pairing acceptation issues and things like that. You must be able to see the images broadcasted by all the people surrounding you, right away.

Comment: Ow, also I shall add something : you don't know in advance who you're connecting to. The point is to meet new people, so basically u'd need to see their faces before you ever interact with them (at least you'd need to "scan" surrounding devices, with or without an associated image)